Best practice to train DeepLabV3 with different resolution images in PyTorch
I am trying to train PyTorch's DeepLabV3 on COCO 2017 dataset for semantic segmetation but I am unsure on how to deal with the different resolution images. I know that DeepLab's architecture can process them without any problems, but I can't stack them in batches due to their resolution. What is the best practice to handle this issue? Do I resize them to a fixed size? Do I take a random crop of fixed size? I know that there are a lot of solutions for this issue, but I don't really know what's the best practice in the context of semantic segmentation training.
Thanks!

There is no ideal option, each choice has its pros and cons. Therefore, I recommend trying all the valid options and compare the performance. You can start with these options:

You can resize images to a slightly larger size e.g., 520x520.
You can randomly crop images to the desired fixed size e.g., 512x512.
You can use both options by starting with resizing and then cropping.

There is an advanced option that you can try which is computing the widths and heights of all images and then calculate the average. Then, use the average width and height to resize all images to.
